# mysql query to filter LIKE combined with IN

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS botPatterns (
  `boltP` varchar(200) NOT NULL
)  ;

INSERT INTO `botPatterns` (`boltP`) VALUES
  ('6X135/6X139.7'),
  ('8X165.1'),
  ('8X165.1/8X170' ),
  ('8X170' );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vehicles (
  `Brand` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Pattern` varchar(200) NOT NULL
)  ;

INSERT INTO `Vehicles` (`Brand`,`Pattern`) VALUES
  ('Audi','6X135'),
  ('Audi','8X165.1'),
  ('BMW','8X170' ),
  ('Ford','9X139.7' );
```

What I need here is to get all Vehicles for which i have boltPatterns.

Example 1. Audi 8x165.1 was contained in table botPatterns

Example 2. For is 9x139.7 was also contained in table botPatterns but under value 6X135/6X139.7

One of the approaches would be

```
select * from vehicles
where pattern in 
(
    select boltp from botpatterns
)
```

But this will return only exact match.

My output here should return all results from table Vehicles beside Ford.

Fiddle : [Fidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26db0/1)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirty

```
SELECT *
FROM botPatterns
JOIN Vehicles ON LOCATE(Vehicles.Pattern, botPatterns.boltP)
```

| boltP | Brand | Pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6X135/6X139.7 | Audi | 6X135 |
| 8X165.1/8X170 | Audi | 8X165.1 |
| 8X165.1 | Audi | 8X165.1 |
| 8X170 | BMW | 8X170 |
| 8X165.1/8X170 | BMW | 8X170 |

More accurate

```
SELECT *
FROM botPatterns
JOIN Vehicles ON FIND_IN_SET(Vehicles.Pattern, REPLACE(botPatterns.boltP, '/', ','))
```

| boltP | Brand | Pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6X135/6X139.7 | Audi | 6X135 |
| 8X165.1/8X170 | Audi | 8X165.1 |
| 8X165.1 | Audi | 8X165.1 |
| 8X170 | BMW | 8X170 |
| 8X165.1/8X170 | BMW | 8X170 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YUSJMpS4)

If you need in brands list only then use `SELECT DISTINCT Vehicles.Brand ..`.